# sharing auth token between web and desktop app

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm developing a webapp that connects to google drive and I'm using PyDrive, the user will authorize my app to connect to their drive and I'll store the oauth credentials

now I also have a desktop client that connects to my webapp and I want to share the saved credentials with the desktop app instead of asking the user to authorize another app, I've done a couple of tests and it works even when the token expire but I want to know if this is something acceptable or if it's forbidden by the google api terms

Answer (score 0):

Although it's geared towards webapp and mobile app, [Cross-client identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#androidIdTokens) may work for your needs.